# delay before reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotifications, reloaddata

I am loading a tableView that populates some of it's elements from another location... I am using NSNotificationCenter to send a message to the view controller to reloadData once the data is loaded into the data source (NSMutableArray)... I have a few NSLogs to help with debugging and there is a huge delay between when the notification is fired and when the tableView actually reloads the data... I think I've tracked it down to a delay in cellForRowAtIndexPath which doesn't have anything fancy at all:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Line *theLine = [theInvoice.lines objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = theLine.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"qty: %@; unit-price: $%@", theLine.quantity, theLine.unit_price];

   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

   return cell;
}
```

I also have an NSLog count the NSMutableArray data source when the notification is received and it logs the correct number of elements... then theres about a 2 second delay before the tableView reloads. Any thoughts on what could be the cause of this delay?

EDIT:
Here is the code for the receipt of the notification:

```
- (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Notification Received, new count: %d", [theInvoice.lines count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData]; 

}
```

In the viewDidLoad method I am subscribing to the notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"updateRoot" object:nil];
```

UPDATE:
I changed my updateView to this and the delay decreased dramatically:

```
- (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Notification Received, new count: %d", [theInvoice.lines count]);

    //[self.tableView reloadData]; 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }); 

}
```

Is this because the UI thread was caught up doing something and switching to the main thread increased the speed?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues when implementing the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method; though, my situation was much more complex.  Do you do anything like that?

Comment: no, not using heightForRowAtIndexPath: it's a pretty vanilla table... the data being loaded is xml so there is a delay for the parsing but that is being completed and then the notification is sent and received far before the table ever reloads... it's a strange pause...

Comment: Do you perform any processing which may possibly be blocking the main thread which may make it appear as though it were slow?  The notification that you are sending out - do you have other objects that subscribe to the same notification which, perhaps, can be processing anything?

Comment: No, no other processing is going on... I parse the XML, send the notification... the TableViewController is idle... receives the notification, theres an NSLog that lets me know the notification was received as well as the new count of the NSMutableArray, then the tableView reloadData is called... then theres the delay, about 2 seconds and the data appears in the table...

Comment: On more thing:  When you NSLog(), are you printing the contents of your array?  NSLog() will block your main thread.

Comment: No, just printing out the count... it idles after the count has been logged then the gap in time occurs before cellForRowAtIndexPath is called

Comment: You shouldn't have to guess where your app is spending its time. Run it using Instruments and find out for sure what is taking so much time.

Comment: I think you are chasing a red herring using dispatch_async on the main queue.  That's essentially the same thing as what you were doing since both are running on the main thread.  You originally mentioned that there was a 2 second delay.  Then you mentioned using dispatch_async decreased the time dramatically.  My gut tells me there is something else going on we aren't aware of.